# how can I automate the eraser or pen tool on Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, path, html5-canvas, dom-events

I made a simple drawing tool and wanted to automate the eraser tool which follows the path I made.

At the moment, there’s a red background and I can use the eraser function I made (just like the eraser tool on illustrator), which means the place where I click will be erased. But I have a specific path, and want the eraser to follow along the path to erase. (like automating the eraser.)

I’m using addEventListener mousemove atm, but I’d like to replace it as automation.

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
  const c = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 20;
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

  c.fillStyle = "red";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  let painting = false;

  function startPosition() {
    painting = true;
  }
  function finishedPosition() {
    painting = false;
    c.beginPath();
  }
  

  function draw(e) {
    if (!painting) return;
    c.lineWidth = 100;
    c.lineCap = "round";

    c.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    // c.strokeStyle = "rgba(10,100,0,0.2)";
    c.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    c.stroke();

    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }

  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", finishedPosition);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Queues

If I get what your are after you can achieve this effect with a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20a%20queue,other%20end%20of%20the%20sequence.)

Basically a queue is an array where you add items to the top, and get items from the bottom.

JavaScript is not particularly efficient at implementing a queue but for 99% of needs it is simple and fast enough.

### Example Simple Queue

This example draw the points at the end of the queue and erases them from the end of the queue

```js
requestAnimationFrame(update);

const BRUSH_SIZE = 10;  // radius Note that eraser brush must be a little bigger to 
                        // cover anti-aliasing edges
const BRUSH_SIZE_ERASE = BRUSH_SIZE + 1;                        
                        
const pointQueue = []; // just a simple array
const queueLength = 48; // howl ong the queue should get before removing items

/* To avoid thrashing the garbage collector we will reuse points by adding 
    old unused points to a pool and taking from the pool rather than create 
    new ones if there are any available
 */
const pool = [];

/* To define points a Vector object */
var temp;   
function Vec2(x = 0, y = (temp = x, x === 0 ? (x = 0 , 0) : (x = x.x, temp.y))) { this.x = x; this.y = y }
Vec2.prototype = {
    init(x, y = (temp = x, x = x.x, temp.y)) { this.x = x; this.y = y; return this }, // assumes x is a Vec2 if y is undefined
};

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const mouse  = {x: 0, y: 0, ox: 0, oy: 0, button: false}
var w = 0, h = 0, cw = 0, ch = 0;

function update(timer){
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
      if (w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight){
        cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
        ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
        
      }
    if (pointQueue.length >= queueLength) {
        let point = pointQueue.shift(); // get point from start of queue
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, BRUSH_SIZE_ERASE, 0, Math.TAU);
        ctx.fill();
        pool.push(point);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    }
        
    if (mouse.button) {
        let point;
        if (pool.length) { point = pool.pop() }
        else { point = new Vec2() }
        point.init(mouse);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, BRUSH_SIZE, 0, Math.TAU);
        ctx.fill();
        pointQueue.push(point);
    }
        
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}


Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
function mouseEvents(e) {
      const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.ox = mouse.x;
    mouse.oy = mouse.y;
      mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
      mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
    mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
    
}
["down", "up", "move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouseEvents));
```

```css
canvas { position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; }
div { pointer-events: none; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div>Click drag to draw</div>
```

### Example 2

The example redraws the points in the queue each frame, to erase the end we simple just remove items from the queue

```js
requestAnimationFrame(update);

const BRUSH_SIZE = 10;  // radius                   
                        
const pointQueue = []; // just a simple array
const queueLength = 48; // how long the queue should get before removing items

/* To avoid thrashing the garbage collector we will reuse points by adding 
    old unused points to a pool and taking from the pool rather than create 
    new ones if there are any available
 */
const pool = [];

/* To define points a Vector object */
var temp;   
function Vec2(x = 0, y = (temp = x, x === 0 ? (x = 0 , 0) : (x = x.x, temp.y))) { this.x = x; this.y = y }
Vec2.prototype = {
    init(x, y = (temp = x, x = x.x, temp.y)) { this.x = x; this.y = y; return this }, // assumes x is a Vec2 if y is undefined
};

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const mouse  = {x: 0, y: 0, ox: 0, oy: 0, button: false}
var w = 0, h = 0, cw = 0, ch = 0;

function drawQueue() {
    ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth = BRUSH_SIZE * 2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (const p of pointQueue) {
        ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();

}

function update(timer){
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
      if (w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight){
        cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
        ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
        
    } else {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    }

    if (pointQueue.length >= queueLength) {
        pool.push(pointQueue.shift()); // get point from start of queue
    }
        
    if (mouse.button) {
        let point;
        if (pool.length) { point = pool.pop() }
        else { point = new Vec2() }
        point.init(mouse);
        pointQueue.push(point);
    }

    drawQueue();
        
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}


Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
function mouseEvents(e) {
      const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.ox = mouse.x;
    mouse.oy = mouse.y;
      mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
      mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
    mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
    
}
["down", "up", "move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouseEvents));
```

```css
canvas { position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; }
div { pointer-events: none; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div>Click drag to draw</div>
```

There are a zillion different behaviors associated with drawing tools. The above just gives example of implementing a simple and efficient queue. How you use it to draw is up to you.

- **Note** Each time an item is shifted `Array.shift` from the queue JavaScript needs to move every item in the array down one index. For very long arrays this can impact performance.

  The best Queue is via a pre assigned array where the start and ends (Head and tail) of the queue are indexs, and no items are ever added or removed. When the start or end index goes past the array length you just move them to the start again.

  However such a queue has a fixed length so you must take care not overwrite the tail.